# jquery animate image stop

Tags: jquery, animation

How can I let this animation stop at the last image and let it stand on the last image?
Maybe you can help me to stop this animation.

```
var myImages = [
    "http://placekitten.com/200/200",
    "http://placekitten.com/150/150",
    "http://placekitten.com/180/180",
    "http://placekitten.com/170/170",
    "http://placekitten.com/140/150",
    "http://placekitten.com/160/160"
];
var counter = 1;  // Start at number 2 since the HTML tag has the first

function switchImage() {
    $('#myImage').attr('src', myImages[counter]);
    counter += 1;

    if (counter == myImages.length) {
        counter = 0;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(switchImage, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval()` returns an interval ID, which you can pass to `clearInterval()`.

```
var refreshIntervalId;
var myImages = [
    "http://placekitten.com/200/200",
    "http://placekitten.com/150/150",
    "http://placekitten.com/180/180",
    "http://placekitten.com/170/170",
    "http://placekitten.com/140/150",
    "http://placekitten.com/160/160"
];
var counter = 1;  // Start at number 2 since the HTML tag has the first

function switchImage() {
    $('#myImage').attr('src', myImages[counter]);
    counter += 1;

    if (counter == myImages.length) {
        counter = 0;
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   refreshIntervalId = setInterval(switchImage, 5000);
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EpPZQ/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much! but how can I let the animation start by clicking on the image? and how can I let the animation start if I visite the page because the animation is already starting when i'm not on the right page jet.

Comment: As you wrapped `setInterval(switchImage, 5000)` in DOM ready animation will start once your page loaded. Put this in image click event.

Comment: @Unkown I have put it like this $(document).click(function() {
    refreshIntervalId = setInterval(switchImage, 50); but now if I click on the whole page or random in the page it self it starts the animation also

Comment: @user2852398 This wont work for image click. You have to replace document with image id/class.

Comment: Alright I think that I better explain what i'm trying to accoplish. I want the user to choose how much times the animation wil be played. The animation exually consists out of two animations, so if the user chooses to play the animation 1 time it comes at the first part of the animation and if he chooses 2 times he comes at the second part of the animation, third time, at the first part again and so on. if the animation is done there has to appear an option to click on. I might need to use adobe flash professional cc for the animation but I have no experience so could you give me an advise?

Comment: would you like to help me? or are you to busy with other things?

Comment: @user2852398 I didn't get you exaclty what you are trying to achieve. Better you can explain clearly with some code that you tried.

Comment: I don't have a code for it yet that is the reason why I am asking this. You can see my problem as a Dice game. The user can choose how much he can throw the dice but now the dice has only two laces.So my question is how can I achieve that if the user wants to throw 5 times the dice comes at the right lace. This in combination with an animation

Comment: So If I understood it correctly, user will select value from dropdown/enter input like 1/2/3... . Based on user input you have to start the animation. Is it correct?

Comment: Then it's super simple. Replace `var counter = 1;` with your `input/select' value.

Comment: No because the animation wil start now at this this number but it has to go from the beginning to the `input/select' value

Comment: No because now the animation starts at http://placekitten.com/170/170 but the animation has to end at http://placekitten.com/170/170 and start at http://placekitten.com/200/200 (if the user fills in the number 3)

Comment: Thats it Thanks! but how do I let the animation start if I fill in for example 5 and pres enter?

Comment: call animation method on button click.

Comment: can you explain how I have to insert this in the code and what I need to fill in for the value="" ?

Comment: Do you know how to use .click event for button? If yes use the same.

Comment: no sorry I don't get it can you explain and explain what I have to use in the html code because now I have this: <img id="myImage"/>
<input id="counter" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> but I dont't think that that is correct

Comment: Hi again I have made an animation in adobe flash professional cs5.5 but I dont know how I can insert this animation into my script. I have already tried it with an spritesheet but I can't solve my problem can you help me?

Comment: post new question with what you are trying to do with your code.

Comment: I have an animation in sprite sheet and now I want the same ystem as above but now not a image has to change but a sprite sheet Has to change